# Splitting of induced module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, vector-bundles

Let $G$ be a unipotent complex algebraic group and $K\subseteq G$ a closed subgroup.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-module, and consider the induced module $\operatorname{Ind}_{K}^{G}V$, the $G$-module which is given by the sections of the $G$-equivariant vector bundle on $G/K$ corresponding to $V$.

Then we have a natural $K$-module surjection $ev:\operatorname{Ind}_{K}^{G}V\to V$.  My question is: does the map $ev$ always have a $K$-module splitting?